# NSArrayController sorting: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key"

Tags: swift, class, sorting, tableview, nsarraycontroller

I´m trying to setup sorting in NSTableView. NSArrayController is bound to an Array: `dynamic var dataArray = [Person]()`. 
Populating the tableView is working so far, but coming to sorting I´m stuck in this error.
My setup is:

1: in IB: ArrayController, Binding Inspector:

```
   - Sort Descriptors bind to ViewController
   - Model Key Path: self.customSortDescriptors
```

2: in IB: tableView, Binding Inspector:

( Here I´m getting error: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key customSortDescriptors.")

```
   - Sort Descriptors bind to ArrayController
   - Controller Key: arrangedObjects
   - Model KEy Path: customSortDescriptors
```

3: in IB: Column "Name", Attributes Inspector:

```
   - Sort Key: name
   - Selector: caseInsensitiveCompare:
```

In ViewController:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arrayController: NSArrayController!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!

    dynamic var dataArray = [Person]()

    dynamic var customSortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataArray.append(Person(name: "Noah", familyName: "Vale", age: 72))
        dataArray.append(Person(name: "Sarah", familyName: "Yayvo", age: 29))
        dataArray.append(Person(name: "Shanda", familyName: "Lear", age: 45))

    }

}
```

Everything works without errors until I set the second step from above: `2: in IB: tableView, Binding Inspector:`Then I´m getting error: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key customSortDescriptors.`

Person class:

```
class Person : NSObject {
    var name:String
    var familyName:String
    var age = 0

    override init() {
        name = "name"
        familyName = "family"
        super.init()
    }

    init(name:String, familyName:String, age:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.familyName = familyName
        self.age = age
        super.init()
    }
}
```

This is a demo project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwRghT926ZpyMVhZMHJqTGFOS3c/view

Comment: Show the code for Person class

Comment: Try not to inherit from `NSObject`.

Comment: @  brianLikeApple: I addded the Person class.

Comment: @  shallowThought: What do you mean by "Try not to inherit from NSObject"? Populating the tableview is working.

Comment: your code is working fine for me.

Comment: @ Dharmesh: even sorting? What am I missing?

Comment: Check this: http://imgur.com/a/HTSBe and code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24980862/

Comment: For more info read here. http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/sort-descriptors-in-swift/

Comment: @ Dharmesh: In Playground it´s working for me as well. But not so in tableView using NSArrayController Bindings.

Comment: can you please share demo project

Comment: @ Dharmesh: here´s the link. I didnt set the tableview Binding in tableview -> Binding Insector. So you can run the application first to see if the building works. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwRghT926ZpyMVhZMHJqTGFOS3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: AND: `name` in this project is `givenName`. Should not make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because the array controller doesn't have a property `customSortDescriptors`

Bind `tableView.sortDescriptors` to `arraycontroller.sortDescriptors` (controllerKey!).

[image]

---

However if you want to enable column sorting by clicking on the header add values for `Sort Key` and `Selector` in the table column:

[image]

In this case you need only the binding from table view to array controller as in the first image.

Comment: If I do so, putting `arraycontroller.sortDescriptors` in controllerKey, the entry jumps in one line below, to Model Key Path. And controllerKey keeps empty. After building same error. http://imgur.com/a/6IokP

Comment: Only `sortDescriptors`, I added an image

Comment: You are right, thank you very much! Also there was a second mistake, hidden in my setup, took a while to find out: `1: in IB: ArrayController, Binding Inspector:` It has to be just `customSortDescriptors `, NOT `self.customSortDescriptors`.